# How to set mouse click as global shortcut in electron app

Tags: electron, node-modules

I want to trigger an action on double `right-click` of mouse when electron app is running in the background.
 I read the documentation and seems like there are no [globalshortcuts](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/global-shortcut.md) for mouse events.

Any other way to achieve this? perhaps some node module compatible with electron app?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we can't achieve that yet.

As MarshallOfSound commented on this official issue

*"globalShortcut intercepts the key combination globally and prevents any application from receiving those key events. If you blocked apps from receiving mouse button presses things would break everywhere very quickly "*

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13964

---

For macOS, I'm currently using Keyboard Maestro App.
I'm getting my mouse keys with this app and triggering a globalShortcut key combination register in my Electron App.

Maybe for Windows, AHK (auto hot keys)

Answer (score -1):

I found this nice solution for HTML code

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
     const {remote} = require('electron')
     const {Menu, MenuItem} = remote

     const menu = new Menu()

     // Build menu one item at a time, unlike
     menu.append(new MenuItem ({
        label: 'MenuItem1',
        click() { 
           console.log('item 1 clicked')
        }
     }))

     menu.append(new MenuItem({type: 'separator'}))
     menu.append(new MenuItem({label: 'MenuItem2', type: 'checkbox', checked: true}))
     menu.append(new MenuItem ({
        label: 'MenuItem3',
        click() {
           console.log('item 3 clicked')
        }
     }))

     // Prevent default action of right click in chromium. Replace with our menu.
     window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        menu.popup(remote.getCurrentWindow())
     }, false)
  </script>
```

Put this as first item in your HTML Body and it should work. At least it worked on my project

EDIT, cause I forgot it: Credits to google for answer on 6th entry

Comment: wil it work if my app is running on backgroud i.e. when the focus is on different application??

Comment: I didn't tested that. So you want your app running in the background, so the right click should replace the windows/linux/max internal context menu?

Comment: yes.. re-read the question and i'm pretty sure this answer won't help